# lazylinker_c import Error Theano

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, amazon-ec2, theano

I'm getting an annoying error.

> You can find the C code in this temporary file:
>   /tmp/theano_compilation_error_ppkcgkmi Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File
>   "/home/ubuntu/my_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/gof/lazylinker_c.py",
>   line 75, in 
>       raise ImportError() ImportError
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/ubuntu/my_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/gof/lazylinker_c.py",
>   line 92, in 
>       raise ImportError() ImportError
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/home/ubuntu/my_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/**init**.py",
>   line 110, in 
>       from theano.compile import (   File "/home/ubuntu/my_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/compile/**init**.py",
>   line 12, in 
>       from theano.compile.mode import *   File "/home/ubuntu/my_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/compile/mode.py", line 11, in 
>       import theano.gof.vm   File "/home/ubuntu/my_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/gof/vm.py",
>   line 673, in 
>       from . import lazylinker_c   File "/home/ubuntu/my_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/gof/lazylinker_c.py",
>   line 127, in 
>       preargs=args)   File "/home/ubuntu/my_project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/gof/cmodule.py",
>   line 2359, in compile_str
>       (status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. '))) Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1):
>   /home/ubuntu/.theano/compiledir_Linux-4.4--aws-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial-x86_64-3.6.4-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory. compilation
>   terminated..

I'm using a P2 Instance from AWS where I installed Ubuntu 16.04.

I'm just trying to `import theano` on python3.6.4

I've re-installed theano many times, also I installed **MANY** other stuff and it's not working.

I have a virtual environment and I'm using the GPU.

I assume my GPU-CUDA-CuNN is well installed

```
>>> sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
2018-03-07 17:56:48.738855: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2018-03-07 17:56:51.390598: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:898] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2018-03-07 17:56:51.390927: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1212] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235
pciBusID: 0000:00:1e.0
totalMemory: 11.17GiB freeMemory: 11.10GiB
2018-03-07 17:56:51.390955: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1312] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-03-07 17:56:51.656494: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:993] Creating TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10764 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 3.7)
Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 3.7
2018-03-07 17:56:51.787214: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:297] Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 3.7
```

In my local machine everything is working perfectly, but on the aws instance it stocks there, and it's the first time I got that error.

I hope someone has seen aleady this kind of error.

**EDIT**

I solved the problem for my project, because I just need Tensorflow and somehow someone imported `np`from `theano` and not from `numpy`. However, it still a weird problem I would like to know how to fix it. Could it be a version problem with numpy?

the line `75` from `lazylinker_c.py` is just about comparing two versions. I don't know.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem for a while with Ubuntu 16.04 when I tried to move on to Python 3.6 from Python 3.5. Finally I discovered that Ubuntu 16.04 does not include the C header files for Python 3.6 by standard, so they need to be installed separately. The theano library somehow uses C for certain calculations. Running the this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev
```

resolved the problem for me.